# Get Data from subscribe and assign to local variable

Tags: angular, typescript

**Angular 6 Service**

```
getProjectEpics(id: string): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'getEpics/' + id);
}
```

**Component Angualr 6**

```
projectEpics=[];
getProjectEpics(id: string) {
this.epicService.getProjectEpics(this.id).subscribe(
  next => {
    console.log('RESPONSE', next);
    this.projectEpics = next[0].epics;
    console.log(this.projectEpics); // array has data
  },
  error => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  }
);
console.log(this.projectEpics); // The array is empty at this log.
}
```

I am using Angularr 6. I have a method returning observable of type any **getProjectEpics** in serive which is calling an API. Then in my component i am subscribing to observable method avaliable in service. I successfully get the data from the API and serive but issue is that when i assign the data present in next object to my local array **projectEpics** and log projectEpics array inside next to console, it displays the array but, when i log it outside next or outside subscribe the projectEpics array is empty and shows no data.

Comment: Make your next as (next), and error as (error) and try

Comment: Maybe `console.log(this.projectEpics);` is called before receiving a response from the server (as it is in this snippet)? Http calls are asynchronous. In that case you just don't wait for answer from Http call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are asynchronous in nature. Javascript is a single thread environment and any asynchronous tasks it detects are handed off to enclosing environment(Browser,NodeJS etc.,) to execute it in a separate thread. When javascript tries to run your code, it does the following:

1. Main thread Call to getProjectEpics()
2. Checks the statement this.epicService.getProjectEpics() and hands off the execution
3. Main thread executes your last console.log() - this happens even before the second step is finished

Array is empty in the last console.log() statement as it won't wait for the API call to finish.

For a detailed explanation, please see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it works when using async calls, you only have access to variables in that scope/thread.  you could use a service / RxJS subjects / ...  to communicate to the outside